# Why npm install speed so slow?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, macos-big-sur

i am using mac book pro - M1 chip and bigsur

but I have a problem.
the speed so slow when i install any library to npm

[please click the picture i have counted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht97x.png)

---

the picture, i had install the 'react-native-fast-image'
but there consumes more 1000s for installed

likewise,
i had typed in terminal, 'npm i or yarn install'

Consumes more than 30 minutes.

---

for solving this, i have tried deleted xcode, and webstrom, and vsc
but, there are no change in speed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this exact same issue. After speaking with Genius Bar we realised I was on an old version 12 of node. Node 15.5 onwards runs natively on M1 so isn't being parsed through Rosetta 2, which was likely causing the lag.

You can check the version of node you're on by running **node -v**

If you're on anything below 15, if you run **nvm install v15** on terminal this might solve your issue by updating your node.

I had an error at this point (you might not) saying:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),
missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

[Which was solved with this.](https://ma.ttias.be/mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun/)

After sorting that, when running nvm install v15 it solved the lagginess :) good luck!

You might also find even after installing the latest node, your terminal defaults to an old version (mine did to much bemusement!)

You can solve it be setting a default, [check this link.](https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm)

In short, run:
**nvm use node**

This switches to the latest installed version of node.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I found this answer out of frustration. I'm on a 2020 PRO and everything is now blazing fast!!!!!!

Comment: I have to use node 12 for a project - which is still extremely slow. do you know how if I can resolve it for an older version somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Today I used for the first time Node/NPM 17 and I got back to these issues of NPM install taking forever.

I switched back to Node/NPM 14 and everything works again just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is in the same situation as me where you need to run nodejs 12:

Install Rosetta, if you haven't already done so

```
$ softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

You might wonder, "how will my M1 Mac know to use Rosetta for a version of node compiled for an Intel chip?". If an executable contains only Intel instructions, macOS will automatically use Rosetta to translate the instructions.

Open a shell that's running using Rosetta

```
$ arch -x86_64 zsh
```

Note: This same thing can also be accomplished by finding the Terminal or iTerm App in Finder, right clicking, selecting "Get Info", and then checking the box labeled "Open using Rosetta".

Note: This terminal session is now running in zsh. If zsh is not the shell you typically use, nvm may not be source'd automatically like it probably is for your usual shell through your dotfiles. If that's the case, make sure to source nvm.

```
$ source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"
```

Install whatever older version of node you are interested in. Let's use 12.22.1 as an example. This will fetch the node source code and compile it, which will take several minutes.

```
$ nvm install v12.22.1 --shared-zlib
```

Note: You're probably curious why --shared-zlib is included. There's a bug in recent versions of Apple's system clang compiler. If one of these broken versions is installed on your system, the above step will likely still succeed even if you didn't include the --shared-zlib flag. However, later, when you attempt to npm install something using your old version of node.js, you will see incorrect data check errors. If you want to avoid the possible hassle of dealing with this, include that flag. For more details, see this issue and this comment

Exit back to your native shell.

```
$ exit
$ arch
arm64
```

Note: If you selected the box labeled "Open using Rosetta" rather than running the CLI command in the second step, you will see i386 here. Unless you have another reason to have that box selected, you can deselect it now.

Check to make sure the architecture is correct. x64 is the abbreviation for x86_64, which is what you want to see.

$ node -p process.arch
x64
Now you should be able to use node as usual.

Instructions from:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#macos-troubleshooting

Note, I didnt use nvm, was using asdf instead.  Had to remove previously installed version of node 12 from asdf and then install it again

Answer (score -1):

For those who cannot move their project to node 15 overnight.

Install node by itself by going on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/download/release) reduce drastically npm library installation on mac book pro - M1 Pro Monterey.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).